# Use Jensen's inequality to prove that $f$ is an increasing function.

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X$ be a random variable, and define $$f(p):= \|X \|_p := \mathbb{E}\left[|X|^p\right]^{\frac{1}{p}} \quad \text{ for } 0 < p < \infty$$ Use Jensen's inequality to prove that $f$ is an increasing function.

*My attempt*: I apply Jensen's inequality to $f(p)$: i.e. 
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\lvert X \rvert ^p ]^{\frac{1}{p}}] \geq \mathbb{E}[\lvert \mathbb{E}[X]\rvert ^p]^\frac{1}{p}$$

But I do not know where to go from here. Any comments or answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Jensen's inequality to (the convex function) $φ(x)=|x|^{q/p}$, with $1\le p <q <+\infty$, to obtain that $$\|X\|_p=\left(\Bbb E|X|^p\right)^{\frac1p}=\left(φ\Bbb E|X|^p\right)^{\frac1q}\le \left(\Bbb E φ\left(|X|^p\right)\right)^{\frac1q}=\left(\Bbb E|X|^q\right)^{\frac1q}=\|X\|_q$$

---

This shows in particular that $L^q\subseteq L^p$. A common application is that if $X_n \overset{L^q}\to X$ then $X_n \overset{L^p} \to X$ for all $1\le p < q$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the edits to the question (I'm new to math.stackexchange) @Jimmy

Comment: @ChristopherBaker You are welcome and ... welcome :)!

Comment: Is it not the case that $L^q\subseteq L^p$ if $1 \leq p \leq q < \infty$. ie if the $q^{th}$ absolute moment exists, then the $p^{th}$ absolute moment exists, but the $p^{th}$ absolute moment can exist when the $q^{th}$ absolute moment does not?

Comment: @ChristopherBaker Yes, of course the inclusion in my post should be the other way round. What you say in your comment is absolutely correct, so I edited my answer.